# My LG Motion is stuck in boot loop after hard reseting

Tags: boot-loop, lg-motion

I tried to install a font using Font Installer on my LG Motion which was rooted, and it went into a boot loop. I hard reset it, but it is still stuck in a boot loop. Help me out, please? If I need to download any files, please, give me a link.

Comment: Might not do the job, but worth a try: have you removed the battery for 10s+, and then re-inserted it? Oh wait, that is a hard-reset -- if you did not mean factory-reset (which would be a last ressort as well). You could try booting into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) and see if that is possible. But if you meant [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) when you wrote "hard reset", that won't help either.

Comment: Once again, I hard reset it because it went into a boot loop. But it is still in a boot loop...

Comment: Once again, too: What do you mean by "hard reset"? Check the [hard-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) (hard reset = take out the battery, put it back again), and the other links from my previous comment -- and then please clarify what you really mean. Often people say "hard-reset" when they really mean "factory-reset" -- and I'm not sure if this is one of those cases. Unless you clarified that, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Actually, Hard reset was the short term originally used for "Factory Hard Reset," which replaces safe mode when it cannot be booted. But if it pleases you, Factory Reset.

Comment: Eff, it's not that I have it with words (as for me, it could be called "potato chipping"). But you will admit that there's a little difference between taking out the battery (hard-reset), and a factory-reset, technically spoken? :) Usually, a factory-reset should *solve* this issue. So if removing power completely for 10s+ doesn't do it, that's really weird -- and might require a flash (see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)). Did you modify something in `/system` before this happened?

Comment: I have already removed the battery for a whole day. I did not touch anything in there. I was just installing a font package. I dont know how to flash or do any of that. I don't even know how to put my phone in fast boot. Do you have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: You probably installed that font-pack to the system partition -- which is why the factory-reset cannot help you, as it doesn't touch `/system`. I have no tutorial for fastboot at hand, but I will try to setup some basic help as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you use a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) to solve a boot-loop -- but it doesn't cause one. Sometimes, a [hard-rest](/questions/tagged/hard-rest) (i.e. removing the battery for at least 10s) solves things, as it makes the entire device powerless so nothing can "stick". In your case, however, none of the two could help:

### Analysis

As it turns out, the culprit is a font-package you installed. A little background on that:

While "normal apps" get installed into the `/data` partition, more system-oriented stuff (font packs, specific frameworks, things changing core system behavior, modded notification bars, and more) need to reside in the `/system` partition. Now, when it comes to a factory-reset, the `/system` partition is never touched -- so if things get messed up there, they stay messed-up. As in your case, obviously.

So what's the remedy? You no longer can boot up normally, as your device is stuck in a boot-loop due to some system mismatch. You also cannot help yourself booting into [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode) to remove the culprit; while this would work for user-space apps (which are not run in safe-mode), you won't even be able to boot into this mode with a messed-up system. This leaves two things:

- if you still can boot into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode), you might be able to undo your changes via `adb shell` from your computer. But this usually requires a custom recovery (such as [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) or [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp)) on your device, as stock recovery won't give you the required root access.
- if you cannot boot into recovery mode, or have no custom ROM installed on the device: re-flashing your [device-firmware](/questions/tagged/device-firmware) will fix your issue for sure, as that would wipe `/system` and install everything anew. With a [stock-rom](/questions/tagged/stock-rom) this usually also means you lost your [root](/questions/tagged/root) access. Flashing in your situation can still be done via either recovery mode (if you can boot your device into it), or [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) mode (if your device supports it; I've read many LG devices need to have the [bootloader](/questions/tagged/bootloader) unlocked to do so)

---

### Flashing needed?

You might want to check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for the [rom](/questions/tagged/rom) to be flashed. Further hopefully helpful links include:

- [Fastboot Commands for LG Android Smartphone](http://www.lg-phones.org/fastboot-commands-for-lg-android-smartphone.html)
- [How to Flash LG Motion 4G](http://www.lg-phones.org/how-to-flash-lg-motion-4g.html)

Abstract from the latter link:

1. get the official firmware from [lg-phones.org](http://www.lg-phones.org/official-lg-motion-4g-firmware-download.html)

   - KDZ_FW_UPD_EN to be extracted to your PC
   - LG Motion `.cab` firmwares need to be converted to `.kdz` (see [Official LG Motion 4G Firmware Download](http://www.lg-phones.org/official-lg-motion-4g-firmware-download.html) for details)
   - `msxml.msi` needs to be installed to your PC (ouch, Windows only, sorry)
2. get the USB drivers from [lg-phones.org](http://www.lg-phones.org/lg-motion-4g-ms770-usb-driver-download.html) and install it
3. start `KDZ_FW_UPD.exe`

   - "Type" choose CDMA
   - Choose in "Phonemode": Emergency
   - Click the folder icon and choose the `.kdz` file that `UpTestEX_mod2_marwin.exe` just made (in step 1).
   - Click "Launch software update"

The rest should run automatically.

---

### Postscriptum

I included a bunch of tags into this question. You might want to follow them:

- click them for questions relevant to the topic
- better: hover your mouse over it, and follow the revealed 'info' link to their "tag wiki". Out tag-wikis often include a good description as well as some "first aid"
- hovering your mouse over them lets you also chose to see...

  - the most frequested questions tagged such
  - top users contributing to that topic (might be helpful to see their profile, as they obviously are "experts" in that area that might reveal further interesting and related questions/answers)